# Squid 502 errors

Tags: squid, 502-error

I am using Squid 3.3.13 with no cache enabled and all my clients in LAN are using it to access to HTTP and HTTPS websites. I am not using it as transparent proxy but clients have it configured in OS preferences.

It works, but I'm getting some random **(104) Connection rest by peer** errors on some websites, for example [www.tim.it](http://www.tim.it) and [www.impresasemplice.it](http://www.impresasemplice.it), like what you see on this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error I'm getting from clients when access one of problematic websites]

The strane things are:

- I am not getting this error from every clients but I have it randomly only on some of them
- I am not getting this error for every websites but only on a list of them
- When I get this error it goes away if I retry to reload the page on the same website 3/4 times
- In the same time I am getting the error on the client I can access the same website from the proxy itself with no problems (using a browser like **elinks** from the command line of the proxy server (CentOS **centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64**)

Looking in the Squid's `access.log` file I see a 502 error when I get the error from the client. 502 error is "bad gateway", but if I have bad gateway why I can access the same website from elinks on the same time?

```
[Thu Jan 19 18:05:26 2017].837     56 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/502 4489 GET http://www.tim.it/ - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 text/html
[Thu Jan 19 18:06:47 2017].655     54 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/502 4525 GET http://www.tim.it/ - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 text/html
[Thu Jan 19 18:06:48 2017].099     60 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/301 591 GET http://www.tim.it/favicon.ico - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 text/html
[Thu Jan 19 18:06:48 2017].136     29 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/200 0 CONNECT www.tim.it:443 - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 -
[Thu Jan 19 18:07:04 2017].305  16165 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/200 19410 CONNECT www.tim.it:443 - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 -
[Thu Jan 19 18:07:13 2017].540     90 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/301 569 GET http://www.tim.it/ - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 text/html
[Thu Jan 19 18:07:27 2017].532  13988 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/200 3396 CONNECT www.tim.it:443 - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 -
[Thu Jan 19 18:07:27 2017].540  13996 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/200 131005 CONNECT www.tim.it:443 - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 -
[Thu Jan 19 18:07:44 2017].743  17196 10.1.3.223 TCP_MISS/200 143879 CONNECT www.tim.it:443 - HIER_DIRECT/156.54.69.9 -
```

Could you help me to find out where I am wrong, please?

Comment: Same problem here, have you made any progress on this?

Comment: Did you try to sniff (with tcpdump) the traffic on the squid host? This could shed some lights on what happens there.